# How to get plain backup files from CommVault Simpana

Tags: backup

Our IT department uses CommVault Simpana to create backups from a server's filesystem, MySQL databases, and PostgreSQL databases.

It is possible to restore those backups on any server known to Simpana.

I'd like to get plain backup files (e.g. individual files from the filesystem backup and MySQL/PostgreSQL database dumps) out of Simpana.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get the back-upped files out of CommVault Simpana.